# How can I clear notification?

Tags: java, android, notifications, cancellation

I have to hide a notification when a timer is cancelling.
I instantiate a notification manager and use

```
myNotificationManager.cancelAll();
```

but it doesn't work.

What do I need to do?

Comment: `cancelAll()` should cancel (remove) all notifications created by your app. If you're trying to remove notifications created by another app, bad luck: you can't.

Comment: I want to clear all notifications of my app, it's not for another app.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem. I added a `stopForeground(true);`. The parameter is a boolean which determine if the notification of the foreground service will be cleared when the service is stopped. My code contained `startForeground` method but there is not a `stopForeground` method. That's why adding it was logical for me.